# Show pdf generated on server with ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, pdf, itext

i have this ajax call:

```
var datiInput = {};

datiInput.idTipo = idtipo;
datiInput.clearEngine = clearengine;
datiInput.nomeFileSvg = numfile;

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(datiInput);

OpenLoading();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handlers/generaDatiTecniciPDF.ashx",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/pdf",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        CloseLoading();
          //i wanna open pdf recived in new tab :(
    } 
});
```

This is my handler ashx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using ImageMagick;

namespace Federal_Mogul.handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descrizione di riepilogo per generaDatiTecniciPDF
    /// </summary>
    public class generaDatiTecniciPDF : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            string datiJson = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

            Input_DatiTecnici obj = Deserialize<Input_DatiTecnici>(datiJson);

            if (obj != null)
            { 
                int idtipo = Convert.ToInt32(obj.idTipo);
                string ce = obj.clearEngine;
                string svg = obj.nomeFileSvg;

                string percorso_svg = @"http://www.website.it/svgs/" + svg + ".svg";

                DatiVeicolo dV = GetDatiVeicolo(idtipo);

                List<DatiTecnici> elencoDatiTecnici = new List<DatiTecnici>();

                //elaboration of elencoDatiTecnici


                CreaFilePDFDatiTecnici(dV, elencoDatiTecnici, idtipo, ce, percorso_svg, context);
            }
        }

        public DatiVeicolo GetDatiVeicolo(int idtipo) //, int idbody)
        {
            // function for getting data of veichle
        }

        public void CreaFilePDFDatiTecnici(DatiVeicolo dV, List<DatiTecnici> dati, int idtipo, string clearengine, string svg, HttpContext context)
        {
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            document.Open();

            //elaboration of pdf

            document.Close();

            context.Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());

        }

        public string GetNumeroSchedaDaBodyType(int idtipo, int idbody)
        {
            // function for obtain schedule number string
        }

        public class GradientTableBackground : IPdfPTableEvent
        {
            //class for managing gradient on table
        }

        public class DatiVeicolo
        {
            public string marca { get; set; }
            public string modello { get; set; }
            public string versione { get; set; }
            public string cod_motore { get; set; }
        }

        public class DatiTecnici
        {
            public int Sort3 { get; set; }
            public int idGruppo { get; set; }
            public string Gruppo { get; set; }
            public int IdSottogruppo { get; set; }
            public string Sottogruppo { get; set; }
            public string Dati { get; set; }
            public string Valori { get; set; }
            public string Discriminante { get; set; }
            public string codMotore { get; set; }
            public string ClearEngine { get; set; }
            public int cTypeId { get; set; }
            public int TypeID { get; set; }
        }

        public class Input_DatiTecnici
        {
            public int idTipo { get; set; }
            public string clearEngine { get; set; }
            public string nomeFileSvg { get; set; }
        }

        public T Deserialize<T>(string context)
        {
            string jsonData = context;

            //cast to specified objectType
            var obj = (T)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonData);
            return obj;
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can response pdf object and show after ajax call in a new tab? Without close any others tab?

Comment: Or i must create pdf file and send link needs? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download it as a blob create a blob url for it and then open a new tab with it.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        window.open(url.createObjectURL(this.response));
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'handlers/generaDatiTecniciPDF.ashx');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
xhr.send(jsonData);
```

Comment: `jsonData` is the json you are sending in the request, so pass your data to the `xhr.send()` function

Comment: oh stupid sorry :). i'll try it now. See you soon and i accept answer if itworks!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.